# Moving multiple files using REGEX to a sub folder

Tags: python, regex, directory

I have some files that include the keyword "Mantech" at the beginning of the file and would like to move them to my "Mantech" folder. I'm looking specifically to move the pdf files that contain the keyword. Code as follows:

```py
import shutil  
import os  
import re  

folder = 'C:/Users/Chris/Documents/ManTech'  
keyword = re.compile(r'(^Mantech)(.*)(pdf$)', re.IGNORECASE)  

for organization in os.listdir('C:/Users/Chris/Documents'):  
`mo = keyword.search(organization)      
    
shutil.move(organization, folder)
```

I keep getting a "FILENOTFOUNDERROR: No such file or directory" error.

Comment: You have permissions for all files and the target folder exists right?

Answer (score 0):

Regex seems to be overkill for that easy task. You could use globbing instead:

```
import glob, shutil
sourcedir = 'C:/Users/Chris/Documents'
destdir = 'C:/Users/Chris/Documents/ManTech/'
gl = 'Mantech*.pdf'
for file in glob.glob(sourcedir+gl):
    shutil.move(file, destdir)
```

The downside is that glob does not support case insensitive globbing.

Comment: Wow it worked! Thank you! I did feel that regex was overkill but was just trying to use it as an exercise. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir()` returns only file names and not the full path. Please use `shutil.move(os.path.join('C:/Users/Chris/Documents', organization), folder)`.

You can move it to a constant of course.

Comment: Ah that was the problem! I really appreciate it thank you.

Comment: @Slatercj I'm glad I could help. If my solution has solved your problem, please be free to click the checkmark next to it and [accept it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). This lets other users know that your question was solved and awards us both a reputation bonus.